# Is Log a compressed table engine in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a `Log` table and also a `MergeTree` table. In the `system.columns` table, it has a column, `data_compressed_bytes`, showing bytes compressed for each column for each table. I can see that the `MergeTree` table showing values under the column but for the `Log` table, the column shows all zeros.

`Log`

```
┌─database─┬─table──┬─name───────────┬─type─────┬─data_compressed_bytes─┬─data_uncompressed_bytes─┬─marks_bytes─┐
│ default  │ logs   │ log_time       │ DateTime │                     0 │                       0 │           0 │
│ default  │ logs   │ start_time     │ DateTime │                     0 │                       0 │           0 │
```

`MergeTree`

```
┌─database─┬─table─────┬─name────────┬─type─────┬─data_compressed_bytes─┬─data_uncompressed_bytes─┬─marks_bytes─┐
│ default  │ logs_m │ log_date    │ Date     │               1221802 │                20000000 │       19536 │
│ default  │ logs_m │ log_time    │ DateTime │              25181624 │                40000000 │       19536 │
```

So, I am wondering if it means that columns in engine type `Log` are actually compressed or not.

[ClickHouse documentation](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single/index.html#document-table_engines/tinylog) states that `TinyLog` is compressed but not sure about `Log` and I don't see that in the `system.columns` table.

Answer (score 3):

**Log** engine compresses column data as well as TinyLog.

Quotes from the [doc](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/single/index.html#tinylog):

> **TinyLog** The simplest table engine, which stores data on a disk. Each
>   column is stored in a separate compressed file.
>
> **Log** differs from TinyLog in that a small file of “marks” resides with
>   the column files.

The information about compressed and decompressed sizes of a column is not reflected into **system.columns** table because **Log** is a quite simple engine (unlike **MergeTree**) and doesn't store a lot of metainformation about own column files (it only maintains **sizes.json** file with compressed column sizes).

So, it is possible to set **system.columns.data_compressed_bytes** for **Log**'s columns, but at the same time **system.columns.data_uncompressed_bytes** will be zero and it may look questionable.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Do you know how I can find out how much compression it has achieved for each column in a table with `Log` engine?

Comment: Yes. But it is quite tricky. You need to install clickhouse-compressor util using apt and run the following:

    for f in /var/lib/clickhouse/data/default/log/*.bin; do echo $f "compressed:" `stat -c "%s" $f` "uncompressed:" `cat $f | clickhouse-compressor --decompress | wc -c`; done

Where /var/lib/clickhouse/data/default/log/ is data dir for default.log table